# Harddisk has suddenly a russian name - hacked?

Tags: macos, ssd, virus

Longterm macOS user here. German system, never had any contact to any kind of russian language or so. Suddenly my "Data" HDD/SSD on 2019 16" MacBook has a russian name.

This looks totally shady to me, has anybody a clue what's going on?

EDIT: The word means "Data" in russian. A quick Bitdefender run says no infections found. I have a dev background, so I'm naturally picky in what I install and where the sources are. No shady software, no unnecessary sudo, the system is mostly default. I mostly work from home (using own wifi), no shady locations.

[image]

Comment: Your [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345793/why-can-other-users-see-my-files-in-my-user-folder) said there were "other users" on your Mac. Is that still the case?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica good catch, but this is unrelated and 3+ years old, on a Mac i dont own anymore. The other question was intended as a hypothetical question, as the "other user" was I myself, switching from private and work accounts on the same hardware, wondering why i could see stuff from the "other" user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information given you cannot conclude either way whether you have been hacked.

Is it normal that the name of a volume suddenly changes its name - no.

Is the only possible cause of such a name change hacking - no.

Given that there is no obvious benefit to a hacker of changing the name of your volume, and that is the opposite of what viruses usually does (i.e. keep low and stay undetected) - it doesn't seem that likely that is is hacking or viruses.

Perhaps it is some software you have installed that changed the name (also unlikely). You mention that you use the computer to work from home, so it might be a Mac managed by your employer - perhaps they issued the name change.

Comment: thanks for having a look! I agree, the most realistic scenario is some kind of software renaming the "Data" partition during some weird scan (?) processes. however, as I worked with crypto and did (non-crypto) payment processing for companies in the past (on totally different machines and years ago), there's always this feeling that is might be some kind of hack. btw I copied over important data to external hdd and reformatted the hardware, started over from scratch, changed important passwords and stopped all running sessions on imporant software. better safe than sorry.

Comment: The Latin plural of virus is not vira, as it's not 2nd declension neuter. If used, it would be viri, but the English plural is viruses. ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy Out of habit I used the Danish plural "vira", as I'm Danish...

Comment: @Sliq I also worked with (non-crypto) payment processing - but I don't have this feeling of everything unusual is probably hacking. Usually it's just an interesting detective style hunt for the logical and non-dramatic explanation.